# Opencart meta title in every page

Tags: opencart, title, vqmod

I have a script for vqmod opencart made in this way:

```
<modification>


   <file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/header.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[<title><?php 

            $separator=" | ";

            $store_name=$this->config->get('config_name');


            if(trim($store_name)!=trim($title))
            echo $title.$separator.$store_name;
            else
            echo $title;


            ?></title>]]></add>
        </operation>
  </file>

</modification>
```

I would like to show in every page not the website name (config_name), but the homepage title that is different and more complete. Moreover it is different for every language of my site. Can you help me in some way?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know what you are looking for, for example in a category or in a product, what do you want to be the site title?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer. I would like to add at the end of the meta title of every page (all of them, products, categories, informations etc) a string of words of my choice. For example if the title is " #productname, #category, #brand " ,  I want it to be " #productname, #category, #brand - #mysitename #mysitedescription". The problem is that #mysitename #mysitedescription have to be different for every language automatically.

I hope to have well explained the problem